# asyncTask called in OptionItemSelected called at the wrong Item

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have some OptionItems with AsyncTask(with a progress dialog) called as shown

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.FilterSpeed:
            GetSpeed();
            break;
        case R.id.FilterEvent:
            GetEvents();
            break;
        case R.id.FilterDevice:
            GetDevices();
            break;
        case R.id.ClearFilter:
            ClearFilter();
            break;
    }
    new GetAllUserDevices(Dashboard.this, Dashboard.this).execute(API_ServiceDev_method_url);
    return true;

}
```

I access the Asynctask data in the 3rd item click (GetDevices) but I get the progress dialog when clicking on the 2nd item (GetEvents) even though  this item have nothing to do with the AsyncTask .

how can I make the progress dialog appears on the right item choice ?

Added : GetDevices

```
 public void GetDevices() {
    DevicesNames = GetAllUserDevices.DevicesNames;
    DevicesIds = GetAllUserDevices.DevicesIds;
    SelectedDevicesIds = new HashSet<>();
    SelectedDevices = new ArrayList<>();
    isCheckedDeviceList = new boolean[DevicesIds.size()];
    if (oldChecked.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < DevicesIds.size(); i++) {
            isCheckedDeviceList[i] = Dashboard.oldChecked.get(i);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < DevicesIds.size(); i++) {
            oldChecked.add(i, Dashboard.isCheckedDeviceList[i]);
        }
    }
    CharSequence[] DevicesNamesInChar = DevicesNames.toArray(new CharSequence[DevicesNames.size()]);
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Dashboard.this);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.Devicename))
            .setMultiChoiceItems(DevicesNamesInChar, Dashboard.isCheckedDeviceList.length == DevicesIds.size() ? Dashboard.isCheckedDeviceList : null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                    Dashboard.isCheckedDeviceList[which] = isChecked;
                    if (isChecked) {
                        Dashboard.SelectedDevices.add(which);
                    } else if (Dashboard.SelectedDevices.contains(which)) {
                        Dashboard.SelectedDevices.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                    }

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.okay, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                    for (int i = 0; i < Dashboard.isCheckedDeviceList.length; i++) {
                        boolean checked = Dashboard.isCheckedDeviceList[i];
                        Dashboard.oldChecked.set(i, checked);

                        if (checked) {
                            Dashboard.SelectedDevicesIds.add(String.valueOf(DevicesIds.get(i)));
                        }
                    }

                    Dashboard.UserEditor.putStringSet("DevicesIds", Dashboard.SelectedDevicesIds);
                    Dashboard.UserEditor.commit();
                    StopTimerTask();
                    StartTimer();
                }
            })

            .setCancelable(true).show();


}
```

in a separated class GetAllDevices (AsyncTask)  :

```
public class GetAllUserDevices extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

//vars declaration
static SharedPreferences UserInfo;
static Context context;
static String UserToken;
static Activity activityTest;
InputToString converter;
public static Loading LoadingDialog;
static boolean IsArabic;
public static BufferedReader in;
static String inputLine;
static StringBuffer response;
public static Text_Value_Pair[] devicesList;
public static ArrayList<String> DevicesNames = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Integer> DevicesIds = new ArrayList<>();
MoveTo moving;

public GetAllUserDevices(Context currentcontext, Activity currentActivity) {
    context = currentcontext;
    UserInfo = context.getSharedPreferences("Login_UserInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    converter = new InputToString();
    activityTest = currentActivity;
    LoadingDialog = new Loading(currentcontext);
    moving = new MoveTo(context);


}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    return POSTJson(urls[0]);
}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
}

public String POSTJson(String url) {
    //User Static Params
    UserToken = UserInfo.getString("Token", "NoToken");
    IsArabic = (new IsArabic(context).IsLangArabic());
    String result = "";
    URL obj;
    try {
        obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Token", UserToken);
        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        result = response.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        moving.LogOffNow();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (!result.endsWith("An error has occurred.\"}")) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        devicesList = gson.fromJson(result, Text_Value_Pair[].class);
    } else {
        devicesList = null;
    }

    if (devicesList != null) {
        DevicesNames.clear();
        DevicesIds.clear();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < devicesList.length) {
            DevicesNames.add(devicesList[i].getText());
            DevicesIds.add(devicesList[i].getValue());
            i++;
        }

    }

    return "Data Updated";

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess progress dialog is appearing because of GetAllUserDevices() AsyncTask is executing after switch case is over..

Please check if you want to execute GetAllUserDevices() in all case??
if not then it should be called in particular switch case.

Comment: I tried too call it in a particular switch case but the progress dialog appeared twice , once on the menu button click and once when the selected item clicked , which is so annoying to have to 0.5 sec multiple progress dialog

Comment: Are you executing AsyncTask in following methods
1)GetSpeed();
2)GetEvents();
3)GetDevices();
4)ClearFilter(); ??

Comment: can you put all code in GetDevice  function and GetAllUserDevices function

Comment: Here you are calling GetAllDevices() in all case because its written below switch case.. 
if you want it to be called in case of case R.id.FilterDevice: then do following change to your code.

switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.FilterSpeed:
            GetSpeed();
            break;
      
        case R.id.FilterDevice:
            
    new GetAllUserDevices(Dashboard.this, Dashboard.this).execute(API_ServiceDev_method_url);
            break;
     
    
and in post execute of GetAllDevice.. call GetDevice(). so GetAllDevice will fire only in case of FilterDevice click